# Convert XML to TCL Object

Tags: xml, parsing, tcl

Greetings,

I'm new to TCL scripting, and I have a very very basic xml file which I need to import information from into tcl.

Example of XML Document Structure:

```
<object>
  <type>Hardware</type>
  <name>System Name</name>
  <description>Basic Description of System.</description>
  <attributes>
      <vendor>Dell</vendor>
      <contract>MM/DD/YY</contract>
      <supportExpiration>MM/DD/YY</supportExpiration>
      <location>Building 123</location>
      <serial>xxx-xxx-xxxx</serial>
      <mac>some-mac-address</mac>
  </attributes>
</object>
```

Etc...

I've seen something called TCLXML but I'm not sure if this is the best route or even how to create the package to use it..

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recommend using the [tdom](http://www.tdom.org/) package for XML parsing, particularly as it includes good integration with XPath so extracting things from the data is easy. It's also pretty fast.

If you're using ActiveTcl, then it's already part of it (though you might need to do a `teacup update` to bring it in from the repository).

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful.  I tried package require tdom and it was not found, so I have downloaded tDom from the website.  How can I set the path to look for this newly downloaded package?

Comment: The directory where you installed it (you did build and install it, yes?) – *or* its parent directory – needs to be on Tcl's `auto_path` list.